# One-way ANOVA: Fail to reject the null by F-statistics, but p-value is smaller than alpha?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, p-value, linear-model

Would someone be able to help me make since of the results for the following hypothesis test?

$H_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3$ versus $H_1:$ not all $\mu_i$'s equal

Decision rule: Let $\alpha=0.10$ and reject the null if $F^* < F_{r-1, n_T - r}(0.90)=F_{3-1, 15 - 3}(0.90)=F_{2, 12}(0.90)=2.806796$

I have the follow results in R: $F^*=0.535$ and $Pr(>F)=0.478$

It seems as though I should fail to reject the null since my F* value is less than the F-test cutoff value, but then my p-value is less than my assumed alpha level. Am I likely doing something wrong in my code/test or is this a possible outcome of one-way ANOVA?

Comment: (1) You would reject the null hypothesis if your $F$ statistic is *larger* than the critical value, not *smaller* as in your question ("$F^\ast <$..."). (2) `pf(0.535,2,12,lower.tail=FALSE)` yields 0.599, not 0.478 as in your question, so something seems to be off. (3) Your p value is 0.478, larger than $\alpha=0.10$, so I'm a bit confused why you write it is smaller. Could you clarify?